# Shift geom_bar right (not center-aligned)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar-chart that looks like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = hp)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1)
```

I want to tweak the `geom_bar` parameters so that the bars are shifted to the right (not centred)...

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = hp)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = position_nudge(x = 0.5))
```

How I figured this out: Went to `?geom_bar` and saw that there was a postion argument and a link to `?position_dodge`. Look at the examples there and made modifications to your code. Seems to be a satisfactory solution.

Comment: I was trying to fiddle around with position_dodge... but it wasn't working. position_*nudge*() is exactly what I need. Thanks!